# How to print Python Output in Entry widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

I've searched through the whole Internet for how to do this, and nothing came to me. There were some similar topics, when programmers asked of how to parse 'int' numbers to the Entry output. But it is much simpler because you just use getters, then insert() - and voila.

I am trying to do the following thing. I print the text written in one line. And for each word I want to count how many times it appeared in the same text.
E.g., I print in my first Entry "*one two one two three*" - I get "*0 0 1 1 0*" in the second Entry widget.
Any non-space sequence of characters is considered a word.

```
from tkinter import *

class DM_3_1:

def __init__(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('250x150')
    root.title("DiscreteMaths_3_1")
    usertext = StringVar()

    Label_1 = Label(root, text="Input")
    Label_2 = Label(root, text="Output")
    inputField = Entry(root, textvariable = usertext)
    outputField = Entry(root)

    inputField.bind('<Return>', lambda _: printLine())

    def printLine():
        counter = {}
        for word in inputField.get():
            counter[word] = counter.get(word, 0) + 1
            Ans = print(counter[word] - 1, end=' ')
            outputField.insert(0, str(Ans))

    Label_1.grid(row = 0)
    Label_2.grid(row = 1)

    inputField.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    outputField.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    root.mainloop()

DM_3_1()
```

What I get in the output now: [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KFEk.png)

As far as you can see, the application works, but there's 'NoneNoneNone...'(depends on the number of characters, including whitespaces) instead of '0 0 1 1 0'. How do I solve my problem? Where's a logical mistake? I guess, it's about the function, but I don't actually see the mistake.

Comment: your line that says `for word in inputField.get():` is likely not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: @Mike Should I define a new variable and mess with it a bit, assigning it to the inputField? 'Cause I can't find appropriate function to this field. I've studied C# for a bit, though it differs so much...

Comment: The statement `for word in inputField.get():` is actually checking each character in the string and not each word. What you want to do to check each word use `.split()` at the end of the `get()` method like this: `for word in self.inputField.get().split():`. This will split up the string by word.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this portion of your code? `self.counter.get(word, 0) + 1`

Comment: @Mike-SMT Just set the initial counter value of words that haven't appeared to zero. And then iterate each non-unique by one.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I've wrote it with .split() as well, before you suggested me, but nothing changed in terms of that 'None' value. I guess it's that Ans variable which is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set Ans to be equal to print rather than the value it was supposed to be. Also your for loop was getting every character rather than every word.

Corrected code:

```
from tkinter import *

class DM_3_1:

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('250x150')
        root.title("DiscreteMaths_3_1")
        usertext = StringVar()

        Label_1 = Label(root, text="Input")
        Label_2 = Label(root, text="Output")
        inputField = Entry(root, textvariable = usertext)
        outputField = Entry(root)

        inputField.bind('<Return>', lambda _: printLine())

        def printLine():
            counter = {}
            words=inputField.get().split()
            for word in words:
                counter[word] = counter.get(word, 0) + 1
                Ans = counter[word] - 1
                print(Ans, end=" ")
                outputField.insert(END, str(Ans))

        Label_1.grid(row = 0)
        Label_2.grid(row = 1)

        inputField.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        outputField.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        root.mainloop()

DM_3_1()
```

edit:

As Mike-SMT pointer out its easier to use `.split`

code edited to use `.split`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is even more appropriate to my task.

Comment: Why not just use `split()` to get the words? Its meant for this task.

Answer (score 1):

So my solutions to this kind of counter is to track each word and keep a list of all the words. Then keep a list of all the unique words. The count each time a unique word appears in the complete list.

I restructured your code a bit to conform a bit better with standards.
I rewrote your `printLine` method to keep track of all the words in a string and create a dictionary that contains a list of all the unique words and how many times they show up in the string.

When writing a class you will need to learn to use `self.` to convert standard variables into class attributes. Class attributes can be accessed from anywhere in the class including methods within the class. Using regular variables will likely cause problems as they are not available to methods after `__init__` has completed.

take a look at the below code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class DM_3_1:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.root.geometry('250x150')
        self.root.title("DiscreteMaths_3_1")

        Label_1 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Input")
        Label_2 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Output")
        Label_1.grid(row=0)
        Label_2.grid(row=1)

        self.inputField = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.outputField = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.inputField.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.outputField.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.inputField.bind('<Return>', self.printLine)

    def printLine(self, Event):
        word_list = []
        counter = 0
        unique_words_in_string = []
        total_times_word_appears = {}
        for word in self.inputField.get().split():
            word_list.append(word)
            if word not in unique_words_in_string:
                unique_words_in_string.append(word)

        for word in unique_words_in_string:
            counter = 0
            for other_word in word_list:
                if word == other_word:
                    counter += 1
            total_times_word_appears[word]=counter
        self.outputField.delete(0, "end")
        self.outputField.insert("end", total_times_word_appears)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    root = tk.Tk()
    DM_3_1(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to note, you've printed the result out to the console, but I changed that for a second. Plus for the solution, for sure. Perfect.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update it to print to the entry field. I have updated my code. Note you will want to clear the entry field each time so add `self.outputField.delete(0, "end")` before you `insert()` anything.